# How to submit form which contain <input type="file"/> in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

**media.html**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="uploadFile(form.value)">
  <input type="file" ngControl="inputFile" />
  <input type="text" ngControl="name"/>
  <button type="submit" >Upload</button>
</form>
```

**media.ts**

```
uploadFile(fileUpload){
    console.log(fileUpload); // this 
    this.mediaService.addMedia(fileUpload).subscribe((r)=> {
        console.log(r);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.text());
      }
    );
  }
```

in line : console.log("fileUpload"); . It print out that :

```
inputFile:null

name: "asdasdasdasd"
```

this mean that I can't catch value of  to submit on my server . how to catch it ? thanks for help !

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383297/angular-2-model-driven-form-with-input-file-file-upload or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399617/angular-2-file-upload-from-input-type-file

Comment: You should use multipart request which is the only way to send input type file

Answer (score 2):

hi in order to send file through form tag you must have attribute

```
ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data"
```

in form tag

which in turn help you in uploading file

Comment: So how does this help one submit the file data?  This is using angular 2+, the form doesn't submit normally.