# Angular2: ng2-file-upload : cannot load it correctly using SystemJS

Tags: file-upload, typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm using systemJS to manage my packages so I've added those lines to my systemjs's configuration file :

```
{
  map: { 'ng2-file-upload': 'node_modules/ng2-file-upload' },
  packages: {
    'ng2-file-upload': {
        main: './ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload.js', // also tried with './ng2-file-upload.js'
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
  }
}
```

I import **ng2-file-upload** via `import { FileDrop, FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';`.

But importing causes my application "craches"  : my typscript compiler seems works well (I can see logs due to other code) but the modifications are not transpiled anymore so I can't run anything. I don't have any error logs in connection with **ng2-file-upload** (except a lot of `Duplicate identifiers`).

Any idea ?

**EDIT:** I've extracted this package from `node_modules` to a folder that is near my app (`vendor`) and I've used a relative path to import `FileDrop` and `FileUploader` but systemjs failed to imports :

`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)`

**EDIT 2:** Here is some details.
My application is under a `public` which contains 2 sub-folders : `src` and `build`. I write ts code inside `src` (this is obvious) and my tsc saves transpiled files to `build`. At the moment, I don't bundle my files so the hierarchy inside `build` is the same as the `src` one.

But something weird happens only with *ng2-file-upload* : during transpiling, tsc add a `node_modules/ng2-file-upload` folder inside `build`. Here is the trees :

```
public
|-- build
|    |-- core
|    |-- modules
|    |-- styles
|    |-- node_modules
|    |    |-- ng2-file-upload
+-- src
    |-- core
    |-- modules
    |-- styes
```

I don't know why TSC transpile this package. Of course, `node_modules` are excluded in my `tsconfig.ts`.

Answer (score 5):

here's my systemjs.config that works:

```
      var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'ng2-file-upload': 'node_modules/ng2-file-upload'
};


var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-file-upload': { main: 'ng2-file-upload.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this configuration:

```
{
  map: { 'ng2-file-upload': 'node_modules/ng2-file-upload' },
  packages: {
    'ng2-file-upload': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    (...)
  }
}
```

and import it this way:

```
import { FileDrop, FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
```

Comment: I've also tried this, but it doesn't works :/. I'm going to add details to my question.

Comment: Which request is executed by SystemJS to load the library (and fails)?

Comment: When I tell SystemJS to import the package by writting `import ...`, it seems that my modifications are not transpiled correctly and my `import` instruction isn't executed. || (maybe there is a conflict between SystemJS and TSC ? Due to a bad configuration ?)