# Getting the server response after xhr.send() in an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I implemented a method to POST a file in my Angular 2 app. It is based on the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985489/2018084).

Because Angular 2  doesn't support file uploads by itself, the solution has to leverage `xhr`. This is what the working solution looks like:

The component method:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.inputModuleService.postFile(this.files).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('sent');
    });
}
```

The service method:

```
postFile (files: File[]): Observable<string> {
    var url = this.uploadURL;

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        var formData: FormData = new FormData()
        var xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        formData.append("upload", files[i], files[i].name);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    observer.complete();
                } else {
                observer.error(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

My issue is that I don't understand how to get the response back to the `onSubmit()` method after the call to `xhr.send()`. Angular2 and the concept of observables and promises are all new to me.

How can I get the server's response from this observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server response is provided to the success and error callbacks of `subscribe()`:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.inputModuleService.postFile(this.files).subscribe(
      response => {
          //response is the server's response, parsed into a javascript object
          console.log('server responded: ', response);
      },
      error => {
          //server response emitted when xhr.status !== 200
          console.error(error);
      }
   );
}
```

This line:

```
formData.append("upload", files[i], files[i].name);
```

Will throw errors because `i` is undefined. The code you copied from had that line within a loop and `i` was the current index. That's not the case in your code.

Your function declaration:

```
postFile (files: File[]): Observable<string>
```

Should be changed to

```
postFile (files: File[]): Observable<any>
```

Because the Observable returned by `postFile` emits objects, not strings.

If you mean to upload just one file, you should also change `files: File[]` to `file: File` and append the file with:

```
formData.append("upload", file, file.name);
```

Comment: My bad for the undefined `i`, that was after I made a temporary change. Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Are observables always `<any>`?

Comment: No, Observables can emit any type. If you expect only strings, then you can use `Observable<string>`.  If you expect a number or a boolean, `Observable<boolean|number>`...