# Angular2: convert XMLHttpRequest to Response

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

Part of existing code

```
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300)
                this.onUpload.emit({xhr: xhr, files: this.files});
            else
                this.onError.emit({xhr: xhr, files: this.files});
        }
    };
```

I'd like to change this code to emit object of type `Response`. So I need to convert `XMLHttpRequest` to `Response`. Is there any ready way to do this or should I write it myself?

Comment: This link may be helpful...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417863/getting-the-server-response-after-xhr-send-in-an-observable

Comment: why do you use xhr directly instead of http service?

Comment: @VictorBredihin This is copy from PrimeNG FileUpload component. I need to upload file.

Comment: @RishikeshTripathy In this SO they emit just JSONified xhr.

Comment: you can use http service with formdata to upload files, then you will get your Response object and emit data on subscribe