# How to Upload Image Angular2

Tags: angular

How can I send a file image in angular2 to my backend?
I have this in my component.html:

```
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]="selectedImage" />
<button  (click)="uploadImage($event, selectedImage)">Save</button>
```

but in my function, `selectedImage` is undefined.

```
uploadImage($event, file) {
    console.log(file); //file is undefined
}
```

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985347/how-to-upload-file-in-angular2

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<div>
    <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
</div>
```

and in the JavaScript:

```
onChange(event) {
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    console.log(files);
}
```

Do not forget to

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng2-file-upload!

```
npm install ng2-file-upload --save
```

Link here: http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/