# how to customize the validation of input type file image

Tags: html, angular

hello I want to validate an input file html type image just accept '`png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif`' and not be greater than 2mb until I can make it possible only that it does not take me `this.firstFormGroup.controls.image .status` if you enter any other file is activated as valid Status.

```
 handleFileInput(event) {

  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const typeFile = file.type.split('/');
  const filemb: number = file.size / 1000000;
  if (filemb <= 2 && (typeFile[1] === 'png' || typeFile[1] === 'jpg' || typeFile[1] === 'jpeg' || typeFile[1] === 'gif') ) {
        const filePath = `${this.rutaImg}/${file.name}`;
        const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
        const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
        this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
        task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            finalize(() => {
              this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
              this.downloadURL.subscribe( url => {
                if ( url ) {
                  this.urlImg = url;
                  console.log(this.urlImg);
                  this.validateImage = true;
                  console.log(this.validateImage );
                  return {
                    isError: this.validateImage
                };
                }
             });
            })
         )
        .subscribe();

  } else {
    this.validateImage = false;
  }
}
```

html code

```
    <div>
        <input formControlName="image"  (change)="handleFileInput($event)" type="file"  id="file" class="inputfile" accept="image/*"  required/>
        <label for="file"><mdb-icon icon="camera"></mdb-icon> Insertar Imagen &nbsp;
          <progress  style="margin-top: -10px; " *ngIf="uploadPercent" max="100" [value]="(uploadPercent | async)"></progress>
       </label>
 </div>
```

FormGroup

```
this.firstFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      ruc: ['', rucValidator],
      razon_social: ['', nameValidator],
      nameBussines: ['', nameValidator],
      phone: ['', phoneValidator],
      describe: ['', describeValidator],
      plan: ['', Validators.required],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      image: ['', this.validateImage]
    });
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo?

Comment: @KiraAG hi I'm trying to make it work I can not adapt the library https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-889iz4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Actually on other note, your approach is valid only. What is the issue you are facing with this approach?

Comment: @KiraAG  the validation is correct only that the this.firstFormGroup is not taking what the validation returns for it is always valid whatever it does in the function handleFileInput ()

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom FormControl, I will show you how to create it([online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpmhu9?file=src%2Fformcontrol%2Fimage-formcontrol%2Fimage-formcontrol.component.ts)) or you can use the npm module ([FileInputAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323198/7291379))

---

Steps for creating FormControl and upload the valid file

1. Implements ControlValueAccessor
2. Added custom validation rules

   - Register for custom validation rules
3. Listen to change events in your reactive forms

   - Upload the valid file to your storage

---

**1.Implements ControlValueAccessor**

image-formcontrol.component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { ImageFormcontrol } from './image-formcontrol';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-formcontrol',
  templateUrl: './image-formcontrol.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-formcontrol.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ImageFormcontrolComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class ImageFormcontrolComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  _registerOnChangeFn;
  _registerOnTouchedFn;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleFileInput(event: Event) {

    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

    this.writeValue({
      file
    });
  }

  writeValue(value: ImageFormcontrol.Value) {
    if (this._registerOnTouchedFn) {
      this._registerOnTouchedFn();
    }

    if (this._registerOnChangeFn) {
      // update value and validity
      this._registerOnChangeFn(value);
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this._registerOnChangeFn = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this._registerOnTouchedFn = fn;
  }

}
```

```html
<input (change)="handleFileInput($event)"  type="file"  id="file" class="inputfile" accept="image/*" />
```

---

**2.Added custom validation rules**

image-formcontrol-validator

```js
  export function allowedTypes(pattern: string[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      const value = control.value as ImageFormcontrol.Value;

      const valid = null;
      const isUndefined = !value || !value.file;
      if (isUndefined) {
        return valid;
      }

      const allowed = new RegExp(`(${pattern.join('|')})`, 'ig').test(value.file.type);
      if (allowed) {
        return valid;
      } else {
        const invalid = { 'allowedTypes': { value: control.value } };
        return invalid;
      }
    };
  }
```

--

*2-1.Register for custom validation rules*

app.component ( you can change it to your component, just for demo purposes )

```js
export class AppComponent {

  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const imageFormControl = new FormControl('', ImageFormcontrolValidator.allowedTypes(['jpeg']));

    this.firstFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      image: imageFormControl
    });
  }
}
```

---

**3. Listen to change events in your reactive forms**

- Upload the valid file to your storage

```js
export class AppComponent {

  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const imageFormControl = new FormControl('', ImageFormcontrolValidator.allowedTypes(['jpeg']));

    this.firstFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      image: imageFormControl
    });

    imageFormControl.statusChanges.subscribe((status) => {
      switch (status) {
        case 'VALID':
          // Upload the valid file to your storage
          const value = imageFormControl.value as ImageFormcontrol.Value;
          this.upload(value.file);
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  private upload(file: File) {
    console.log('upload', file);

    /* your custom logic

    const filePath = `${this.rutaImg}/${file.name}`;
        const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
        const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
        this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
        task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            finalize(() => {
              this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
              this.downloadURL.subscribe( url => {
                if ( url ) {
                  this.urlImg = url;
                  console.log(this.urlImg);
                  this.validateImage = true;
                  console.log(this.validateImage );
                  return {
                    isError: this.validateImage
                };
                }
             });
            })
         )
        .subscribe();

      */
  }
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for the help, I'm trying to adapt it to my logic but I can not do it when loading the image `writeValue (value: ImageFormcontrol.Value)` `this._registerOnTouchedFn, this._registerOnChangeFn`, I do not understand its functionality, apart from it you never activate `validateImage.statusChanges.subscribe ((status)`

Comment: `registeronchange` function : [Registers a callback function that is called when the control's value changes in the UI](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#registeronchange)

Comment: You can fork my [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpmhu9?file=src%2Fformcontrol%2Fimage-formcontrol%2Fimage-formcontrol.component.ts).

Add your logic to the example and describe what you want to do and what you tried and what problems you encountered,hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a stackblitz that could help you or help anybody. Is not perfect, but after reading and research a lot. I make this only for validate file extensions.

https://angular-fileupload-custom-validator-reactive-form.stackblitz.io

I resume here:

1. Create a Custom Validator for your FormGroup or Form Builder.
2. Add it to your component and define array of allowed extension
   files.
3. Return invalid or valid state to your input form.

Answer (score 0):

### Custom validation for required files for input type of file

### requiredFileType.ts

```
import { AbstractControl, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
export function requiredFileType(type: string[]) {
  return function(control: FormControl) {
    // return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const file = control.value;
    const valid = null;
    if (file) {
      // console.log(file);
      var path = file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, "");
      //   var el_down = path
      //     .split("\\")
      //     .pop()
      //     .split("/")
      //     .pop();

      const extension = path.split(".")[1].toUpperCase();
      console.log(extension + "extension" + type.length);
      var existValue: boolean = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
        let typeFile = type[i].toUpperCase();
        if (typeFile === extension.toUpperCase()) {
          console.log("type" + typeFile);
          existValue = true;
        }
      }
      if (existValue == true) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return {
          requiredFileType: true
        };
      }
      return null;
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

### component.ts

```
 this.addSlot
        .get("FileUpload")
        .setValidators([
          Validators.required,
          requiredFileType(["jpg", "png", "txt"])
        ]);
```

### html

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
          <input
            type="file"
            formControlName="FileUpload"
            [class.is-invalid]="FileUpload.invalid && uploadPanel"
            class="form-control"
            (click)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"
            #inputTypeFile
          />

          <!-- <button onclick="document.getElementById('abc').click()">
            choose file
          </button> -->
          <div *ngIf="FileUpload.invalid && uploadPanel">
            <small *ngIf="FileUpload.errors?.required" class="text-danger"
              >File is required</small
            >
            <small
              *ngIf="FileUpload.errors?.requiredFileType"
              class="text-danger"
              >File is required</small
            >
          </div>
        </div>
```