# How to submit reactive form with input type as a File with data for that file?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I need to save a CSV files' content in my Reactive Form as an input value for the Form Control. Currently only file name is selected by default and I need to save File data for that Form Control instead of just the file name.

I tried one of the approach mentioned here: [Angular 7 : How do I submit file/image along with my reactive form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242237/angular-7-how-do-i-submit-file-image-along-with-my-reactive-form)

It says to patch the Form Control value with the file data. When I try following this approach, I get following error:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.
>       at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setProperty
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:134583:18)
>       at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.setProperty
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:133181:27)
>       at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.setProperty
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85257:23)
>       at DefaultValueAccessor.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.DefaultValueAccessor.writeValue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:86345:24)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:87606:27
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88761:65
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.setValue
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88761:28)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.patchValue
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88776:14)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:89118:38

```
 onFileChange(event, formCotrolKey: string) {

     if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
          [formCotrolKey]: file
        });
        // need to run CD since file load runs outside of zone
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation worked for me exactly as I needed using `ControlValueAccessor`. For this you simply need to create a Directive that implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

Use the following code below:

```js
import { ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

let noop = () => {
};

@Directive({
    selector: 'input[type=file][observeFiles]',
    host: {
        '(blur)': 'onTouchedCallback()',
        '(change)': 'handleChange( $event.target.files )'
    },
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: FileInputValueAccessorDirective,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class FileInputValueAccessorDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

    private elementRef: ElementRef;
    private onChangeCallback: Function;
    private onTouchedCallback: Function;

    // I initialize the file-input value accessor service.
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

        this.elementRef = elementRef;
        this.onChangeCallback = noop;
        this.onTouchedCallback = noop;

    }

       public handleChange(files: FileList): void {
     
           if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.multiple) {

              this.onChangeCallback(Array.from(files));

           } else {

            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        
            reader.onload = () => {        
            this.onChangeCallback(files.length ? reader.result.toString().split(',')[1] : null);
                this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
            };                
        }
    }
    
    public registerOnChange(callback: Function): void {
        this.onChangeCallback = callback; 
    }
  
    public registerOnTouched(callback: Function): void {
        this.onTouchedCallback = callback;
    }
    
    // I set the disabled property of the file input element.
    public setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
    
    public writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (value instanceof FileList) {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.files = value;
        } else if (Array.isArray(value) && !value.length) {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.files = null;
        } else if (value === null) {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.files = null;
        } else {
            if (console && console.warn && console.log) {    
                console.log('Ignoring attempt to assign non-FileList to input[type=file].');
                console.log('Value:', value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now include this directive in your module file under declarations array:

```js
// Your Directive location
import { FileInputValueAccessorDirective } from 'app/forms/accessors/file-input.accessor';

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [
    ...
    FileInputValueAccessorDirective
  ]
})
```

Finally in your Component template use:

```html
<input observeFiles [(ngModel)]="fileContent" type="file" />
```

Make sure you have the variable `fileContent` in your component to save the data. That is all needed. Data will be saved in base 64 format in the variable `fileContent`.

If do not need base 64 Encoding you can replace following line in your directive:

```
this.onChangeCallback(files.length ? reader.result.toString().split(',')[1] : null);` inside `reader.onload
```

method with this line:

```js
this.onChangeCallback(files.length ? atob( reader.result.toString().split(',')[1] ) : null);
```